# How do I send an email and redirect from the same button

Tags: php, html, web, paypal, e-commerce

I have a problem that when I try to redirect a customer to paypal website and send an email to the merchant, it says that `POST parameter "id" is required`, but when I remove the email sender, it redirects successfully. Here's the code:

```
<div class="float-right">
                            <form method="post" action="">
                            First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
                            Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
                            Phone number:<br><textarea rows="5" name="phone_num" cols="30"></textarea><br>
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?=$offer->GetData()["id"]?>" />
                                <button class="btn btn-primary" name="send">Zarezerwuj</button>
                            </form>
                    </div>
```

this is "email sender" in the same file as ^

```
<?php
require_once "settings.php";
require_once BASE_DIR."/template/navbar.php";

$id = GET("id", true);

try {
    $offer = new Offer((int) $id);
}
catch (Exception $ex) {
    http_response_code(404);
    exit("Error: Product not found");
}

if (isset($_POST["send"])) {

    $to = "testing@gmail.com";
    $first_name =  $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $phone_num = $_POST['phone_num'];
    $subject = "Zamowienie";


    $message = "Imię: " . $first_name . "<br>Nazwisko: " . $last_name . "<br>Numer telefonu:" . $phone_num . "<br> Pokój:" . $offer->GetData()["title"];



    $headers = "From: testing2@gmail.com\r\n";
    $headers.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
    $headers.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n";


    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    http_response_code(302);
    header("Location: /order/createOrder.php");
}

?>
```

and this is the paypal payment redirection where I set a POST request

```
$total = 0.0;
$order = [];
$id = POST("id", true);
$offer = new Offer((int) $id);

$item_list = new ItemList();

$row = $offer->GetData();
$item_list = new ItemList();
      $item = new Item();
      $item->setQuantity(1);
      $item->setPrice($row["price"]);
      $item->setCurrency("PLN");
      $item->setName( $row["title"]);
      $item->setDescription( $row["short_description"]);
      $item_list->addItem($item);

      $total += $row["price"];
      $order = $row["id"];
```

Comment: Assuming this `/order/createOrder.php` is your paypal redirect I suspect `mail()` is throwing some warning try silencing by appending `@` in front of it

Comment: Have your tired to AJAX the form?